# Find the longest musical substring

Tags: code-golf, string, music

A *musical string* is any string that can be played on a piano keyboard.

For those of us who weren't forced to learn the piano as kids, here is what the keyboard looks like.

[image: piano]

So the string `feed a dead cabbage` is a musical string because every single letter corresponds to one of these nots.

Your challenge is to write a program that takes a string as input from STDIN, and finds the longest musical substring. Then your program must print the substring, and it's length. Here are some sample inputs/outputs.

> Input: "FEED ME! I'm hungry!"
>
> Output: feed 4

> Input: No no no, no musistrin!
>
> Ouput: 0

> Input: `"A **bad** !!!fAd82342"`
>
> Output: abadfad 7

> Input: "Good golfing!"
>
> Output: dg 2

## Rules

- Your output may be upper or lower-case, but there must be no punctuation or spaces.
- There will capitalization and punctuation in the input string, but this doesn't affect whether or not a substring is considered "musical" or not.
- There must be a space between the musical substring, and the number.

Comment: Full programs only, no functions?

Comment: @AlexA yes, full program.

Comment: Can the output be mixed case?

Comment: @nderscore yes, it can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
pdJef!-T<G7+k.:@Grz0)lJ
```

2 bytes saved thanks to @Jakube.

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=pdJef!-T%3CG7%2Bk.%3A%40Grz0)lJ&input=%22FEED+ME!+I%27m+hungry!%22&debug=0) [Test harness.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Fz%2Bz.z+%0ApdJef!-T%3CG7%2Bk.%3A%40Grz0)lJ&input=%22FEED+ME!+I%27m+hungry!%22%0ANo+no+no%2C+no+musistrin!%0A%22A+**bad**+!!!fAd82342%22%0A%22Good+golfing!%22&debug=0)

Explanation:

- `rz0`: The input, in lowercase.
- `@Grz0`: Strip any non-alphabetic characters.
- `.:@Grz0)`: Generate all substrings.
- `+k.:@Grz0)`: Add in the empty string.
- `f ... +k.:@Grz0)`: Filter over these strings.
- `-T<G7`: Filter each string for non musical characters.
- `!-T<G7`: Negate the result. This is `True` if and only if the string was musical.
- `f!-T<G7+k.:@Grz0)`: Filter out the musical strings.
- `ef!-T<G7+k.:@Grz0)`: Take the last such string. `.:` orders substrings by size, so this is also the longest musical substring.
- `Jef!-T<G7+k.:@Grz0)`: Assign the result to `J`.
- `pdJ`: Print `J`, with `d`, space, as the ending character.
- `lJ`: Then, print the length of `J`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>83</s> 75 characters

Fairly self-explanatory.

```
puts"#{s=gets.gsub(/[^a-z]/i,'').split(/[^a-g]/i).max_by &:size} #{s.size}"
```

Takes advantage of the fact that Ruby can split strings on regex (`.split(/[^a-g]/)`).

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 58

```
#!perl -p
$\=0;map{$i++;$\="$& $i"if/[a-g]{$i}/i}(s/\W//gr)x y!!!cd
```

Use:

```
$ perl ~/mus.pl <<<"FEED ME! I'm hungry!"
FEED 4
```

or

```
$ perl -pe'$\=0;map{$i++;$\="$& $i"if/[a-g]{$i}/i}(s/\W//gr)x y!!!cd' <<<"FEED ME! I'm hungry!"
FEED 4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 268

```
class Z{public static void main(String[]a){String s=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]",""),t;for(int i=s.length();i-->0;)if(!(t=s.replaceFirst("^(.*)([a-g]{"+i+"})(.*)$","$2")).equals(s)){System.out.println(t+" "+i);break;}}}
```

Expanded:

```
class Z {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        String s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", ""), t;
        for (int i = s.length(); i-- > 0;) {
            if (!(t = s.replaceFirst("^(.*)([a-f]{" + i + "})(.*)$", "$2")).equals(s)) {
                System.out.println(t + " " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, <s>98</s> 94 bytes

```r
p=strsplit(gsub("[^a-z]","",readline(),T),"[^a-gA-G]+")[[1]];m=max(n<-nchar(p));cat(p[n==m],m)
```

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
# Read from STDIN and remove all non-alphabetic characters
r <- gsub("[^a-z]", "", readline(), ignore.case = TRUE)

# Split r into a vector of substrings on characters other than a-g
p <- strsplit(r, "[^a-g]+")[[1]]

# Get the number of characters in each substring
n <- nchar(p)

# Get the length of the longest substring
m <- max(n)

# Print the string and length
cat(p[n == m], m)
```

Suggestions are welcome!

Note: The output is now mixed-case, which is allowed per the OP's edit. This saved 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [golflua](http://mniip.com/misc/conv/golflua/), <s>84</s> <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```lua
B=I.r():g("%A",""):g("[^a-gA-G]"," ")M=0Q=""~@W B:gm("(%w+)")?#W>M M=#W Q=W$$w(Q,M)
```

I first <s>force lowercase, then</s> strip <s>spaces</s> non-letter characters, then remove all non-musical letters on the input (stdin). I then scan through each remaining word and compare its length before outputting the largest and length (stdout). There's probably a shorter way to do the loop, but at the moment this is what I've got.

An ungolfed Lua code would be

```lua
Line = io.read()                                  -- read stdin
NoSpaced = Line:gsub("%A","")                     -- strip non-letter chars
MusicalLetters = NoSpaced:gsub("[^a-gA-g]", " ")  -- remove non-musical letters
WordLen = 0, LongWord = ""                        -- helpers
for words in MusicalLetters:gmatch("(%w+)") do    -- scan for longest word
   if words:length() > WordLen then 
      WordLen = words:length()
      LongWord = words 
   end
end
print(LongWord, WordLen)                          -- output solution
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5 (106)

```
use List::Util reduce;$_=lc<>;s/[^a-z]//g;$_=reduce{length$a>length$b?$a:$b}m/[a-g]+/g;print"$_ ",0+length
```